# How do I randomize what a discord bot says?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my first time making a discord bot, here's my code, it seems to work, but it only randomizes it when I run it, then it repeats the same message, how would I make it choose a new quote each time?

```
import os
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()

q_list = ('It came to me. My own. My love. My own. My precious', "Lost! Lost! My Precious is lost!!", "Bagginses? What is a Bagginses, precious?", "What has it got in its nasty little pocketses?", "Curse it and crush it! We hates it forever!")

random_q = random.choice(q_list)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('smeagol'):
        await message.channel.send(random_q)

bot_token = os.environ['bottoken']

client.run(bot_token)
```

Comment: Just create the `random_q` variable inside the `on_message` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `random_q` a local variable inside the `on_message` event as it will pick a random one each time someone says `smeagol`.

```py
import os
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()

q_list = ('It came to me. My own. My love. My own. My precious', "Lost! Lost! My Precious is lost!!", "Bagginses? What is a Bagginses, precious?", "What has it got in its nasty little pocketses?", "Curse it and crush it! We hates it forever!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('smeagol'):
        random_q = random.choice(q_list)
        await message.channel.send(random_q)

bot_token = os.environ['bottoken']

client.run(bot_token)
```

You should really use `discord.ext.commands` as its preferred if you create commands.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", case_insensitive=True)

q_list = ('It came to me. My own. My love. My own. My precious', "Lost! Lost! My Precious is lost!!", "Bagginses? What is a Bagginses, precious?", "What has it got in its nasty little pocketses?", "Curse it and crush it! We hates it forever!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('smeagol'):
        random_q = random.choice(q_list)
        await message.channel.send(random_q)

bot_token = os.environ['bottoken']

bot.run(bot_token)
```